# xslt - selecting an attribute value from an xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file as:

```
<BatchTable>
  <UUThref SocketIndex='0 - CCM'
           UUTResult='Passed'
           URL='C:\OverrideCallbacks_BatchReport[4 16 2012][4 14 18 PM].xml'
           FileName='OverrideCallbacks_BatchReport[4 16 2012][4 14 18 PM].xml'
           ECAFailCount='1'
           Version='StationPartNumber=55555StationSerialNumber=2222TPSPartNumber=1234'/>
</BatchTable>
```

In order to pick the Version in the xsl file I have:

```
<xsl:value-of select="BatchTable/UUThref/[@Version]"/>
```

This does not return any value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should give you a syntax error that tells you exactly what you are doing wrong - it's a pretty lame XSLT processor if it doesn't point to your error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It should be

```
BatchTable/UUThref/@Version
```

not

```
BatchTable/UUThref/[@Version]
```

...where are you getting the square brackets from?

---

I've tested the following, and it definitely works:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m 'BatchTable/UUThref/@Version' -v . <test.xml
```

...this command line works by applying the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="BatchTable/UUThref/@Version">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Even without square bracket it does not pick the value of Version.

Comment: @rkk - Does `//UUThref/@Version` work? If so, try `/UUThref/@Version`; this will narrow down where the relevant document root is.

Comment: What programming language are you using for the conversion?  Some XSLT processors will be picky about having `<?xml ..>` in your XML file, etc.  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @rkk Added an example using XMLStarlet to demonstrate successfully selecting from the document using the given path. If you can't replicate that, we'll need to talk about which tools you're using.

Comment: I am using javascript. It does not return any error just nothing gets returned for the Version field (or for any other field  like SocketIndex etc)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - When I try with //UUThref/@Version it works. But /UUThref/@Version does not work.Not sure what the difference is but will use the first one. Thanks!!

Comment: Is there a way to display 'StationPartNumber=55555 StationSerialNumber=2222 TPSPartNumber=1234' values in new line after reading? There is a space between each variable but the names are dynamic. Sorry new to xsl.

Comment: @rkk to get XMLStarlet to give you a version of the XSLT that prints newlines between the selected values, add `-n` to the end of the command line. If you want to split the selected value into elements... you should ask about that as a separate question.